# Explicit constructor and overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, raii, explicit-constructor

```
template<typename T>
class RAII
{
public:

    explicit RAII( T* p = 0 ): p_(p){}

    ~RAII() {delete p_;}

    T& operator*() const { return p_;} 
    T* operator‐>() const{ return p_;}
};
```

---

```
//Usage example:
{
      RAII<std::vector<int>> r(new std::vector<int>());
      std::cout<<r­‐>size()<<std::endl;
} // The std::vector<int> is automatically deallocated
```

---

Hi guys :)

My question: What is the purpose of the explicit constructor and the two operator overloadings in this specific case, and how are they used in the usage example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: there's two errors: p_ is not declared, and the return in `operator*` should be `return *p_`.

---

Anyway, the explicit is so the constructor can't be called implicitly.

Consider this:

```
class Example {
public:
    int x;
    Example(int x) : x(x) {}
};

function ex(const Example& e) {
    std::cout << e.x;
}

int main() {
    ex(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Do you expect this to compile? It does.  And it outputs 5. The reason is that an Example is implicitly constructed.  Basically the `ex(5)` is silently turned into `ex(Example(5))`.  Marking a constructor as explicit forbids this behavior.  If you added an explicit to the constructor, this would be a compile time error.

---

As for the operator overloading, what you have here is a basic 'smart' pointer.  (I would probably use one of the standard ones in C++11 or boost if you can't use a compiler that has the standardized ones by the way.)

Operator overloading allows an object to react to objects in a specific way.  In this situation, operator overloading is allowing the class to pretend to be a pointer over the same type that it's containing.

```
RAII<std::vector<int>> r(new std::vector<int>());
std::cout<<r­‐>size()<<std::endl;
```

`r` is pretending to be a `std::vector<int>*` via operator overloading here.  What is really happening is that it's being called as:

```
(r­.operator->())->size()
```

`operator->` returns a `std::vector<int>*`, so the second `->` is accessing that and calling the `size()` method.

Another example of operator overloading that you're probably familiar with is std::vector's `operator[]`.  `operator[]` returns a reference to an element.

Operator overloading is of course not always used to pretend to be doing already built in things. Consider `ostream`'s `operator<<`.  Rather than the bitshift operator, it puts data into a stream.

---

More information: [standard smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) / [boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) / [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) / [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Oh, and your code violates the very commonly adhered to [rule-of-three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) (or [rule of five in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)).  As it is, your class will double delete a pointer if a copy is made.

```
RAII<int> p(new int)
RAII<int> q = p;
//when q's destructor runs, bad bad things will happen since p's destructor already deleted the int.
```

Comment: So the purpose of the operator overloadings, is to use "r" as a pointer with the -> operator or as a reference with the * operator?

I understand the difference between a implicit and explicit constructor, but I'm still not clear about the purpose of this line:

"explicit RAII( T* p = 0 ): p_(p){}".

What is the explicit constructor doing with p and p_ ?

Comment: @user1960649 For your first question: Yes, pretty much. As for your second question: that's called an initializer list. It has nothing to do with the constructor being explicit. It just means that p_ is initialized to whatever the value of p is.